# How to judge a list and list have the same value

Tags: python, list

I have two list in python like this :

```
A_list=['admin', '_member_'] 
B_list=['admin', 'agents', 'sales', 'dev']
```

if `A` and `B` has same return `True`

Comment: `if A and B has same return True` - do you mean if both of them have at least one common element, then return True?

Comment: what's wrong with `A == B` ?

Comment: Even if someone happened to guess what you were after, you should still edit your question to make it clear what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `any` to see if at least one element  is in common with both:

```
any([item in A_list for item in B_list])
```

---

```
>>> A_list=['admin', '_member_'] 
>>> B_list=['admin', 'agents', 'sales', 'dev']
>>> any([item in A_list for item in B_list])
True
>>> B_list=['student', 'agents', 'sales', 'dev']
>>> any([item in A_list for item in B_list])
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "do `A` and `B` have any elements in common, ignoring position", that's really a set operation: it's just asking whether the intersection is non-empty.<sup>*</sup> So:

```
if set(A).intersection(B):
    return True
```

---

If, on the other hand, your question is "do `A` and `B` have any elements in common *at the same position*", then that's definitely a sequence (list) operation, but Python has a really easy way to zip a pair of sequences up into a sequence of pairs:

```
if any(a==b for a, b in zip(A, B)):
    return True
```

---

<sub>* This also happens to be more efficient than searching `B` iteratively for each element in `A`, but usually that doesn't matter for small values like yours; the fact that it's clear and there's pretty much no way to get anything subtly wrong, on the other hand, do matter.</sub>

Comment: if agents Order is change，
zip return
[(u'_member_', 'agents'), (u'agents', 'admin')]

Comment: @贺文红 I have no idea what you're trying to say there. `zip(A, B)` for lists `A` and `B` does not change the order of the elements in `A` or `B`.

Comment: @贺文红 In particular, with your samples, `zip(A_list, B_list)` is `[('admin', 'admin'), ('_member_', 'agents')]`. And the first pair is equal, so the `any` expression will be true.